# How to set ReadTimeout and ConnectionTimeout for Drive Service using Google Drive Java SDK

Tags: java, google-drive-api, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've been having a lot of issues with `SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` as well as `ConnectException: Connection timed out`. For one thing, I'm a bit confused as to what this error actually signifies with regards to Drive - i.e., [did the request fail, or is it ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518231/sockettimeoutexception-read-timed-out-on-insert-to-google-drive-is-it-retryab)?

**Further, I don't see a way to modify the underlying HttpClient's timeout settings.** I got a hint from [an answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026613/how-to-avoid-read-timeout-when-requesting-all-files-google-drive-api) of how to increase the underlying HttpClient's settings for this.

I'm using a Drive Service with domain-wide access. Here's how I set it up:

```
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setHttpRequestInitializer(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                    public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
                        credential.initialize(httpRequest);
                        httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(180 * 1000); // 3 minutes
                        httpRequest.setReadTimeout(180 * 1000); // 3 minutes 
                    }
                }).setApplicationName("MyApp").build();
```

After testing, I still get `ConnectException: Connection timed out` after only 130 seconds (not the 180 seconds I've set in the Drive Service initialization).

Is this the right way to set this values? If so, what may be another problem? If this is the wrong way to set these values (ConnectionTimeout and SocketTimeout for underlying HttpClient) what is the correct way?

Comment: The underlying library is here https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client. (I know it's on GitHub now but I think some of the documentation got left behind). This might help https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/HandlingTimeoutsAndErrors