# Drive REST API V3 Java Wrapper - upload with progress

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to upload a new file to a drive account using the V3 API and get upload progress. My current(working) code is the following:

```
 val fileMetadata = File()
        fileMetadata.name = newItemName
        fileMetadata.parents = mutableListOf(destFolder.remoteId)

        val osFile = java.io.File(filePath)
        val mediaContent = FileContent(getMimeType(filePath), osFile)

        val file = googleDriveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                .setFields("*")
                .execute()
```

Is it possible to add some kind of a progress listener to a current solution or i need to use another service(like MediaHttpUploader)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-download) which uses the `CustomProgressListener` class.

```
class CustomProgressListener implements MediaHttpDownloaderProgressListener {
  public void progressChanged(MediaHttpDownloader downloader) {
    switch (downloader.getDownloadState()) {
      case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
        System.out.println(downloader.getProgress());
        break;
      case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
        System.out.println("Download is complete!");
    }
  }
}

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/driveFile.jpg");

DriveFiles.Get request = drive.files().get(fileId);
request.getMediaHttpDownloader().setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
request.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
```

Here are additional references you can use:

- [How to get progress of a file being downloaded from google drive using REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369580/how-to-get-progress-of-a-file-being-downloaded-from-google-drive-using-rest-api)
- [File Upload with Java (with progress bar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254719/file-upload-with-java-with-progress-bar)
- [Google Drive API Progress Bar Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787828/google-drive-api-progress-bar-bug)